# Why don't I get the option to Upgrade during Windows 7 Setup?

Tags: windows-7, installation, upgrade

I tried to upgrade windows 7 from my disk and even from my friends disk.

if i start windows 7 and then start setup  i never see this screen.

[image]

if i boot from cd, i see that screen, but when i click upgrade, it tells me to start windows and then begin setup.

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: i have windows 7 x64 ultimate and the disk is same

Comment: @bilalfazlani: No worries. I think Mario's answer is correct. Some advice: Please put a little more effort into your writing your posts (better title, as well as better spelling and grammar if you're able to). Too many typos or vague words makes people not want to put in the effort to answer you.

Comment: The last edit that was done to this question made it even more vague.  I have to downvote for the simple the fact, the user is unable or not willing, to full explain what their question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to do an upgrade, start setup from within your existing Windows installation.

If you'd like to do a fresh install (i.e. the second option), boot directly off the DVD (either change boot priority in BIOS or use some hotkey to determine the boot medium; look in your BIOS manual for reference).

The whole selection is essentially misleading, cause one option will always just tell you to do the other thing, rather than letting you pick that option.

Comment: yes i want to do upgrade. and i am running setup after starting windows. cant  see that screen. does this have to do anything with my disk?

Comment: The whole process might have changed with Windows 7, so I guess it automatically does an upgrad rather than a fresh install. Otherwise (e.g. not having a valid upgrade option), it would show the selection again with the first option being greyed out. If you're unsure, just do a full disk backup (something you should do anyway before upgrading your OS), then install/upgrade.

Comment: 1 - when i booted from from dvd and tried to install it said : start windows, begin setup and CHOOSE UPGRADE.

Comment: 2 - when begin setup from windows, screen dint show up, i tried to contiune installation, it said ur previous windows files will be stored in windows.old folder.

Comment: Okay, maybe something outdated. Or it detects an incomplete previous installation? Did you cancel the installation at any time (e.g. by powering down)? Also: What version of Windows have you got so far?

Comment: no. i never did. windows is working perfectly.

Comment: its just that i messed up directx files

Comment: and now i cant play games :(

Comment: windows 7 x64 ultimate

Comment: and even the disk is same version

Comment: Ah, so you'd just like to "repair" your installation? That's not possible using the upgrade function. You can try to boot from the DVD and use the recovery options to let it search for issues. But if you've got DirectX issues, best bet would be upgrading/reinstalling graphic card drivers as well as getting the latest DirectX Web Setup (from http://download.microsoft.com/). Create a new question if you're having issues with this.

Comment: I have already updated graphics drivers.
n tried re installing dx . it  wont work.

Comment: repair option does not fox dx files.

Comment: Please create a new question with the exact error message you receive (or simptoms you suffer) when playing a particular game. That way we're able to help you a lot faster.

Comment: i also tried to fix this with sfc. but it said all system files are correct

Comment: thank u very much for the efforts though. i see what i can do

Comment: okay. i will do that

Comment: Just install DirectX again, you don't need to repair Windows, to fix DirectX.  This is like pulling your roses because there are weeds around them.

Comment: @Ramhound: that is not really an option for me. I have tried everything to install directX. posted in forums. upgrading windows 7 was the only option left.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upgrade the current windows from which you started the installation, then you may have to do it by booting directly from the DVD.

Comment: no maaan..
i got the screen but when i clicked on upgrade, it says start windows and then choose upgrade. and it never gives that screen when i start installation from windows.!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should boot from the DVD (when booting your system) and not from within your current Windows environment. In the latter it will assume that you want to do an upgrade.

Comment: yes i want to do upgrade. and i am running setup after starting windows. cant see that screen. does this have to do anything with my disk?

Comment: @bilalfazlani - You cannot upgrade to Windows 7 if you are already running Windows 7.

Comment: @Ramhound : yes you can. I am positive about that. and here is the prrof : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2255099

Answer (score 1):

The reason you don't see the screen is, most likely, because you're already running Windows 7. There is nothing to upgrade.

#### Additional Information

To **upgrade** your Windows installation you **must** boot into Windows and install from there. If you want a **custom** installation, you **must** boot from a Windows installation media.

> To perform an upgrade, you can't start, or boot, your computer from the Windows 7 installation media.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-7)

So you will only have one valid option in either case.

However, the source linked above shows that there *should* be the selection screen. But, to my understanding, it will always be an upgrade installation when performed *from* a booted Windows installation.

Comment: when booted in win7 and startet installation, it will create windos.old folder and do clean installation if selected.

Comment: or else if upgrade is selected, it will upgrade. IDEALLY.

Comment: @bilalfazlani: Okay, what's your question?

Comment: WHY DON'T I GET TO SEE THAT SCREEN WHEN STARTED INSTALLATION FROM WINDOWS ? I WANT TO UPGRADE.

Comment: @bilalfazlani: It has already been explained to you several times. Yet, you fail to respond to those suggestions. You boot from the DVD, you click *Upgrade*, it tells you to boot into Windows and start setup, you boot into Windows and start setup. **It now upgrades Windows**, so what exactly is the issue? You **can not** perform a *custom* installation from Windows. You can only upgrade. Or am I missing something?

Comment: :( ok. but it doesnt upgrade. it will put all files in windows.old folder and do clean installation even after doing setup from windows. sorry for the dumb post.

Comment: @bilalfazlani: What version of Windows do you have installed?

Comment: win 7 ultimate x64

Comment: @bilalfazlani: Well, you can't upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 7. The Upgrade option is only for if you have Vista or XP. That's most likely also the reason why you don't see the screen at all.

Comment: upgrade option is there. its called in-place upgrade. i am thinking that option is not showing up because of low disk space in c drive. i'll make some space and then try again.

Comment: @bilalfazlani - First you don't even have free space to install Windows 7.  The second problem you have is you are ALREADY running Windows 7.

Comment: GUYS I GOT THE ANSWER TO MY STUPID QUESTION :d :d

IT WAS THE DISK SPACE PROBLEM !

SOLVED